# How to make button stay on the bottom when soft keyboard goes up

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a button at the bottom of the screen and I want it to stay down even if soft keyboard goes up, but currently it goes up with soft keyboard. I tried to align the button to bottom but with no success.

Here is the code (buttons are within id/activity_form_button_frame):

```
<RelativeLayout>
     <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/activity_form_button_frame"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/activity_form_next_button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        android:src="@drawable/next_btn_drawable"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:padding="5dp"
        />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/activity_form_sumbit_button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        android:text="SUBMIT"
        android:textColor="@color/buttonBlue"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:padding="15dp"
        style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Large"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/activity_form_fragmentcontainer"
        android:layout_below="@id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/activity_form_button_frame"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Check my answer below.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In `AndroidManifest.xml`, set `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` to your activity.

**Like this.**

```
<activity
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
```

**Or:**

```
<activity
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize">
```

**Also you can do this Programmatically.**

> Use this code in `onCreate()` method:

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);
```

Check this for [Reference](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html).

Comment: with the code: android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"     how do we adjust how far from the keyboard the widgets go ? For example , in my case i want a button to be above the keyboard but under the EditText so the user can type and then click the button.How do i achieve that ?

Answer (score 3):

try this....

```
<activity
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
<activity
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
```

or in code

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try add in manifest to your activity attribute android:windowSoftInputMode.
Set it to adjustResize or adjustPan. One of these will work.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your manifest file under your activity tag just add this line.

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize"
```

For Example,

```
<activity
    android:name="packagename.ClassName"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize" >
</activity>
```

And you are good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Change at your `AndroidManifest` file and at `activity` to add property like

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

to this direct to open keyboard to above button.

Answer (score 0):

In your manifest file under activity tag add the following line.

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize"
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `AndroidManifest.xml` try this code:

```
<activity
            android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was using `<item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>` in my theme. It was creating problem and I used `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` along with that.

Answer (score -4):

You can use `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` for that.

Comment: I did for inside RelativeLayout, no result (see the code)

Comment: @bvk256 you have to do this for Button

Comment: and make the height of your RelativeLayout match_parent