# Make TextView not move when keyboard is on screen

Tags: android, android-layout, keyboard, android-edittext

I have a `TextView` that keeps moving every time I tap on my `EditText` and open my soft input keyboard. The `EditText` is located at the bottom of the page. I want it so that the `TextView` that I have doesn't move when the keyboard appears. In my case, the `TextView` is called `No comments to display.` Here is an example of what happens when I click on my `EditText`

[image]

Originally, the `TextView` is contained within the lighter grey area below but when I click on the `EditText`, it is pushed up. Here is my code:

```
public class Comments extends AppCompatActivity {
    private TextView noCommentsView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.comments);
        EditText comment = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.write_comment);
        TextView noCommentsView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.no_comments_text);
        getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);
        getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
        noCommentsView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);         
    }
}
```

Now I know that `adjustResize` simply pushes everything up which is why the `TextView` gets pushed up so high. However, I want it so that the `TextView` stays put where it is. I have tried to use `getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_NOTHING);` and this accomplishes my goal but the `EditText` does not move with the keyboard because the entire layout is not adjusted. Is there any way around this? Is there any way to move up the `EditText` but not have the `TextView` move up? Thanks!

Comment: Did you try `adjustPan`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of check my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37162919/how-to-make-button-stay-on-the-bottom-when-soft-keyboard-goes-up/37163111#37163111

Answer (score 4):

put your `getWindow()` methods above `setContentView()`. Or Else remove `getWindow()` methos from code and add  `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden"` in manifest file.

Comment: Hi, even with adjust resize, my view is pushed up. That is what I was using the entire time. Even if I add it into my `Manifest` file my problem is still there. Any other ideas?

Comment: if you are using full screen mode then it will not work

Answer (score 1):

on `AndroidManifest.xml`

add this: `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize"`

Did this work for you?
good luck with the project :)

Comment: Hi, even with adjust resize, my view is pushed up. That is what I was using the entire time. Even if I add it into my `Manifest` file my problem is still there. Any other ideas?

Comment: with wich adtivity are you ussing?

Comment: I am extending AppCompatActivity

Comment: it happen the same to me, because i was using an activity that add buttons under toolbar and the things in bottom i cant see, but i pushe thm up and it worked :)
try to push up

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean to try to push up?

Answer (score 0):

checkout [THIS](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/04/updating-applications-for-on-screen.html) post on Android Dev blog. most important for you might be line

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

about `adjustPan`

> **The activity's main window is not resized to make room for the soft keyboard.** Rather, the contents of the window are automatically panned so that the current focus is never obscured by the keyboard and users can always see what they are typing. This is generally less desirable than resizing, because the user may need to close the soft keyboard to get at and interact with obscured parts of the window.

more about other options/flags [HERE](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft)

Comment: Hi, the problem with `adjustPan` is that the entire view gets panned and the current view gets focus. The issue with this is that the top, darker grey part of my screen gets pushed out of the view which is what I do not want. Any other tips?

Comment: This way is proper for keyboard "issue", now the problem is probably with your viewport then. Try to set to your scrollable view `android:fillViewport="true"` as [HERE](http://www.curious-creature.com/2010/08/15/scrollviews-handy-trick/)

Answer (score 0):

android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|stateHidden"

Answer (score 0):

In the android Manifest, add the line:

android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan".
adjustPan says:

The activity's main window is not resized to make room for the soft keyboard. Rather, the contents of the window are automatically panned so that the current focus is never obscured by the keyboard and users can always see what they are typing. This is generally less desirable than resizing, because the user may need to close the soft keyboard to get at and interact with obscured parts of the window.

Source: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html